# How to test inline installation of Chrome extension in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, google-chrome-extension, protractor

In my Angular app, I use [inline installation of my Chrome extension (more in the Chrome docs here)](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

Now I somehow want to "emulate" and test the installation of the extension in the Selenium browser using Protractor. Something like

```
element(by.id('installbutton')).click();
expect(browser.inlineInstallExtensionWindow()).toShowUp(); // something like that
```

I am using the standard `webdriver-manager` and `jasmine2` as a framework (because of some issues with older version of jasmine).

Comment: Feel free to tell me if it doesn't answer your question, I'll be happy to reverse the dupe.

Comment: It does, but it seems (unfortunately) far too complicated :( but thanks for pointing me in the right direction